# can't see menu in android

Tags: android, menu

i am beginner in android. 
I am trying to create a menu for a training app.
I don't know my menu isn't printed.

i have a simple menu on res/menu/menu/home.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.gon.myapplication.HomeActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:title="@string/app_name"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

and on my activity i try to display it

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Do i make something wrong ? thx for your help.

Comment: change app:showAsAction to android:showAsAction="ifRoom"

Comment: Add the `style.xml` file first in your `values` the `styles`

Comment: Edit your question add the `style.xml` code!

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your activity has an action bar or a Toolbar as an action bar.

And use `return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);` instead of `return true;`.

Also consider using `app:showAsAction="never"` in your menu item.

Comment: it doesn't fix anything when i change this attribute

Comment: it still doesn't work, i create a new project, the code was exactly like I wrote it before and it work i don't understand.

Comment: In the question, you are telling the menu file is at `res/menu/menu/home.xml`. It should be `res/menu/menu_home.xml`

Comment: yeah i did a mistake, but i found the issue: i forgot to print the toolbar on  OnCreate  `Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`

Comment: now i'm thinking, is not really what i though, because i see other people print there menu without this code on onCreate().

Comment: If the theme already contains action bar, it is not needed to set the toolbar as action bar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Add this line of code
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
    return true;
}
```

**EDIT**

okay if you forgot to close the menu with a closing tag do this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 tools:context="com.example.gon.myapplication.HomeActivity">
 <item
android:id="@+id/action_settings"
android:orderInCategory="1"
android:title="@string/app_name"
app:showAsAction="always" />

 //add this

 </menu>
```

If this is not your mistake then replace your xml file with this

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  >
<item
android:id="@+id/action_settings"
android:title="@string/app_name"
/>


</menu>
```

and keep the java code exactly the way I told you to do above.

Comment: i try but it doesn't change anything